# sample size for 2 dichotomous and 1 continuous predictors, with 1 continuous criterion

Tags: multiple-regression

assuming effect size = .15 and alpha = .05 and power = .80
for 1 continuous criterion and 3 predictors (1 continuous, 2 dichotomous)
what would be the minimum N I would need?

using Gpower, it looks like I'd need N=55 for 3 predictors, but that seems to assume continuous predictors.

from Gpower, for an effect size = .30, a point biserial correlation would require N=82

I'm not sure how to put these pieces of information together, but would a minimum N of 82 provide power of at least .80 ?

I do not expect to have a problem with multicollinearity (based on prior research with these variables).